# Delete file in cloud storage from cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to make a Google Cloud Function which deletes images linked to person object in Firebase realtime database.. But every time I'm getting "Error during request" error (without any specific error.code, it's just undefined).. Here is a function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({ 
  projectId: "PROJ_ID",
  keyFilename: "SERV_ACC.json LOCATED IN FUNCTIONS FOLDER"});

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.removePersonImage = 
functions.database.ref("users/{userId}/persons/{personId}")
 .onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
   const person = snapshot.val();    

   if (!person.photo || !person.photo.key) {
    console.log("Person doesn't have photo");
    return true;
   }

   var path = "user/" + context.params.userId + "/" + person.photo.key + ".jpg";

   console.log("Bucket path: " + path);

   return gcs.bucket(path)
    .delete()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Image " + person.photo.key + " successfully deleted");
      return true;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("Failed to remove image " + person.photo.key);
      console.error("Error: " + err.message);
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting the reference to a Bucket with the path of a File.

You should first create a reference to your Bucket and then use the `file()` method on the Bucket to create the File object.

First declare the bucket from the root bucket name you see in the Storage console but without `gs://`, as follows:

```
const bucket = gcs.bucket("***projectname***.appspot.com");
```

Then declare your file with the the "directories".

```
const file = bucket.file("user/" + context.params.userId + "/" + person.photo.key + ".jpg");
```

Then call delete:

```
return file.delete()
    .then(() => {
    ....
```

See https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#file

and https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Storage#bucket

Comment: Using that code i got 404 error "No such object".. path to file is correct.. Looks like it's trying to find file with the name context.params.userId + "/" + person.photo.key + ".jpg".. Tried also move userId to path in bucket() function.. but got error during request error.

Comment: @Anton I've updated my answer and successfully tested it. The bucket shall be the root bucket name, and not "user".

Comment: Yes... looks like i found out it too, 5 minutes ago :)... Anyway thanks! My mistake was that i used top level folder as bucket name.. Also i removed gcs and used firebase.admin().storage() api.. And it works great without configuring any extra service account.

Comment: Actually the fact that you have to add `.appspot.com` to the bucket name is not very well documented... if you look at https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#file it shows the following example: `const bucket = storage.bucket('albums');
const file = bucket.file('my-existing-file.png');` which gives the impression you should use you top folder (sub-bucket)....

Comment: Worked for me but I had to import and use GCS like this: import 
{ Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';
const gcs = new Storage();

Answer (score 0):

```
 const storage = new Storage({
      credentials: {
        client_email: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        private_key: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET_PRIVATE_KEY,
      },
      projectId: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET_PROJECT_ID,
    });

 bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.STROAGE_BUCKET_NAME);

 const imageParts = user.thumbnail.split('/');\

  bucket.file(`${imageParts[imageParts.length - 1]}`)
      .delete()
      .then((res) => {})
      .catch((error) => {});
```