# how to delete image in firebase storage using cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

so I have a firestore trigger function written using nodeJS, when a document in firestore is deleted, then I also want to delete the image stored in Firebase storage, the name of the file in storage is the same as the deleted document ID. here is my function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

// initialize firestore database
const admin = require("../utilities/firebase_admin_init")
const db = admin.firestore()
const storage = admin.storage()

// firestore reference
const eventRef = db.collection('events')

exports.firestoreDeleteEventCleanUp = functions.firestore.document('events/{eventId}').onDelete((snapshot,context) => {

    const eventID = context.params.eventId

    // how to delete the image in firebase storage in here ????

})
```

and the admin initialization

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

module.exports = admin
```

in Android, I can do this to delete image in storage

```
// Create a storage reference from our app
val storageRef = storage.reference

// Create a reference to the file to delete
val desertRef = storageRef.child("images/desert.jpg")

// Delete the file
desertRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener {
    // File deleted successfully
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
}
```

but now I am using admin SDK, and I don't know how to delete that file using admin SDK. I have tried to read the documentation in here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start . but I don't know what to do to delete the image in firebase storage like the image below

what is the equivalent of `storageRef.child("images/desert.jpg")` if using firestore trigger ?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084684, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50679125, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45356384/ and more from these search results https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+cloud+functions+delete+file+from+storage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in the documentation [item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) you refer to, the "Firebase Admin SDK depends on the Google Cloud Storage client libraries to provide Cloud Storage access." You should use the [Node.js Client Google Cloud Storage](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/index.html?authuser=0).

In particular, you need to use the [`bucket()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html#bucket) method of [`Storage`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html) and the [`delete()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#delete) method of [`File`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html), as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore()  // <- actually this is not needed for the CF below
const storage = admin.storage()

exports.firestoreDeleteEventCleanUp = functions.firestore.document('events/{eventId}').onDelete((snapshot,context) => {

    const eventID = context.params.eventId

    const defaultBucket = storage.bucket(); 
    const file = defaultBucket.file("eventThumbnail/" + eventID);

    return file.delete();

});
```